# Customizing django form based on currently logged in user

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

This is a part of my forms.py

```
class SubjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
title=forms.CharField(label='',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'maxlength':150,
                                                             'placeholder':'Write here. . .'}))
body=forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'Extend here. . .'}))
board=forms.ModelChoiceField(label='',queryset=Board.objects.all(), empty_label='Select Board')
class Meta:
    model = Subject
    fields = ('title','body','board')
```

Right now it's rendering all Board objects in board form field but I want to render only those boards in which the user has subscribed. How can I get user in form and manipulate it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

forms.py:

```
class SubjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title=forms.CharField(label='',widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'maxlength':150,
                                                                 'placeholder':'Write here. . .'}))
    body=forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'Extend here. . .'}))
    board=forms.ModelChoiceField(label='',queryset=Board.objects.all(), empty_label='Select Board')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(SubjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if user is not None:
            self.fields['board'].queryset = Board.objects.filter(user=user) 

    class Meta:
        model = Subject
        fields = ('title','body','board')
```

views.py:

demo with CreateView:

```
class SubjectCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = SubjectForm
    template_name = 'subject/create.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(SubjectCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()

        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            kwargs.update({
                'user': self.request.user,
            })
        return kwargs
```

or

```
form = SubjectForm(**{'user': request.user})
```

Comment: can you please convert CreateView into normal views.py code? I don't have enough django experience.

Comment: `form = SubjectForm(**{'user':request.user})`