# Retrieving Values from ModelMultipleChoiceField Checkboxes

Tags: python, django, forms, model

Big Picture: *Ultimately I have no idea of if I approached this correctly but this is as far as I have got.*

I am building a platform for lawn care industry service providers. Each company is capable of offering different services so I setup a model that allows each service provider to create their own services.

When the service provider sets up an appointment for their customer, I want them to be able to select from a list of checkboxes.

I large in part referenced this thread to get the logged in users entries to display. [Customizing django form based on currently logged in user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937261/customizing-django-form-based-on-currently-logged-in-user)

I have gotten as far as displaying the list of services correctly based on the logged in user but I am having trouble with the POST processing/validation.

The form saves correctly everywhere EXCEPT where the checkboxes are selected. I ultimately want those saved into a Charfield in a different model "form_a" in a comma delimited format.

[image: Here is the display of my current form.]

Corresponding portion of the View:

```
def new_booking(request):
    page_title = "New Booking"
    template = 'jobs/new-booking.html'
    customer_id = request.GET.get('customer')
    customer = ''

    form_a = AddJob(request.POST or None)
    form_b = AddJobDatePicker(request.POST or None)
    form_c = PersonForm2(request.POST or None)
    form_d = AddJobServices(**{'user': request.user})

    more_info = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form_a.is_valid() and form_b.is_valid():
            services = filter(lambda t: t[0] in form_d.fields['service_name'], form_d.fields['service_name'].choices)


            a = form_a.save(commit=False)
            b = form_b.save(commit=False)
            d = form_d.save(commit=False)
            # a.customer_id = CustoemrDB.objects.values_list('completed', flat=True).get(pk=pk)
            # a.booking_id = Jobs_DB.objects.values_list('pk', flat=True).get(pk=pk)
            a.customer_id = CustomerDB.objects.get(pk=152)
            a.service_request = services
            a.date_scheduled = b.date
            a.payment_method = 'visa'
            a.save()
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            return redirect('new-booking')
```

Form:

```
class AddJobServices(forms.ModelForm):
    service_name = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        queryset=ContractorServices.objects.values_list('service_name', flat=True),
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(AddJobServices, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_errors = True

        if user is not None:
            self.fields['service_name'].queryset = ContractorServices.objects.filter(service_parent=user).values_list('service_name', flat=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ContractorServices
        fields = {'service_name'}
```

Model:

```
class ContractorServices(models.Model):
    service_parent = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    sub_service = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)   # this isn't currently used but might be at some point.
    archive = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
```

I am not sure if I approached this correctly and am willing to start over but I feel like I'm close. I was also told on Discord that ModelMultipleChoiceField are for M2M relationships only, but the setup I have was the only way I could get it to display correctly.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you need to check in POST for checkbox name if is True then do something

Comment: how would I go about doing that given all field names are dynamically generated?